# What does "trying to catch smoke with your bare hands" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)* movie, Bem says this words about Sirius Black who arrived at Duff Town:

> Bem: It's like trying to catch smoke... like **trying to catch smoke
> with  your bare hands**.

What does "trying to catch smoke with your bare hands" mean?

Comment: Do you think catching smoke with your hands is easy or difficult? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's meant to illustrate something impossible, you can wave smoke away (if there isn't too much of it) but you aren't going to capture it in any meaningful sense with just your hands.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to catch smoke is obviously difficult, but I’ll assume you got that much because you didn’t bold the first use.

Doing something “with your bare hands” is a way of intensifying difficulty because it rules out any clever tricks or tools you might use to make it easier.  For instance, an iron worker can bend steel, but Superman can bend steel *with his bare hands*.